# Importing pages with different node ids to the live site

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n, importing-exporting

We have a site in drupal 6.

It's placed in 2 different server with separate databases. One is used for staging and the one is used for live.

We have created a new language section and imported the data with xliff tool to the staging. We have completed the modifications in staging and now we need to push them to live.

But the thing is that the node id's are different in staging and live, and also some pages contains view , block and nodes.

And also I must say that I am a newbie in drupal.

I would appreciate if someone could show me a way to import this new language pages to the live site without using xliff.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am closing this as too broad, but this topic has come up many times on this site.  Search for a while and see if any of the solutions help.  Unfortunately, this isn't the easiest operation in Drupal 6 and 7.  If you still need help with select portions, narrow your question down a bit and flag for re-opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem myself in the past, and importing nodes into a livesite can be quite a head ache at times.

Luckily there's a great module available for D6 called [Node Export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export). It allows you to import / export nodes using a host of different formats such as JSON, CSV, XML etc.

I've used it before exporting a large dataset and I was impressed with how easy it was to implement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. I'll try it soon enough and write it the results here.

Comment: I'd like to thank you again. It has been very helpful and saved me a lot of time. Cheers.

Comment: No problem Onur, glad I could help out. I'm sure syncing content between D6 environments has given me a few extra grey hairs over the years :)